# different limitation for each case when condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case-when

i would like to put limitation in case when block for specific condition, is there a simple way for it;

i have a sql like this ; i would like limit condition 4,5,6 to 50K;

```
select SUBSCRIBER_KEY,
coalesce(
    case when pct_1 >90 then  
                case when <condition_1> then 'L_1' 
                     when <condition_2> then 'L_2'
                     when <condition_3> then 'L_3'
                end 
    else null end,
    case when pct_2<=90 and t.wk_dec_pct<=0.2 
                then
                case when <condition_4> then 'L_4' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                     when <condition_5> then 'L_5' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                     when <condition_6> then 'L_6' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                end
    else null end,
    case when pct_2<=90 and t.wk_dec_pct>=0.2 and t.acc_type='main' 
                then
                case when <condition_7> then 'L_7'
                     when <condition_8> then 'L_8'
                     when <condition_9> then 'L_9'
                end
    else null end                                                
)      
from table_t t
where ...
```

Comment: What do you mean "put a limitation"?

Comment: i mean; i have 10mio subscriber in table_t, when i run the code i get 120K in L_4 (condition_4), i want to get not 120K but 50K

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSCRIBER_KEY,
coalesce(
    case when pct_1 >90 then  
                case when <condition_1> then 'L_1' 
                     when <condition_2> then 'L_2'
                     when <condition_3> then 'L_3'
                end 
    else null end,
    case when pct_2<=90 and t.wk_dec_pct<=0.2 
                then
                case when RecordIndex <= 50000 then 'L_4' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                     when RecordIndex <= 100000 then 'L_5' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                     when RecordIndex <= 150000 then 'L_6' --to limit output of this condition 50000
                end
    else null end,
    case when pct_2<=90 and t.wk_dec_pct>=0.2 and t.acc_type='main' 
                then
                case when <condition_7> then 'L_7'
                     when <condition_8> then 'L_8'
                     when <condition_9> then 'L_9'
                end
    else null end                                                
)      
from 
(SELECT
    SUBSCRIBER_KEY,
    pct_1,
    pct_2,
    wk_dec_pct,
    acc_type,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyOrderColumnForConsistency) RecordIndex
FROM    
    table_t) t
where ...
```

Alternatively you could calculate the L_ value using something like the following:

```
case when pct_2<=90 and t.wk_dec_pct<=0.2 
                    then
                    'L_' + CAST((RecordIndex / 50000) + 4 as varchar(2))                    
                    end
        else null end,
```

I can't help but think that this query should be constructed in a better way though.

Comment: thanks for your help. i tried RecordIndex, it bring result less than 50K but it didnt cap, for example count of L_5 was 120K, after adding your suggestion it bring 33K. i want to get result capped with 50K. *L_1,L_2.. are symbolic, in real, we put long segment name D_1_2_er_max_1_use_and_get_ZV